# How to write the code to find items in MongoDB by keywords?

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, pymongo

I can use the following query to find items by id:

```
 DATABASE = None
    
 def initialize():
    client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")
    DATABASE = client['testdb']
    
 def find(collection,query={"_id": id}):
     return DTABASE[collection].find(query)
```

How do I write the method to search items by keywords?
Below two steps need to be executed from mongo console if I want to search the keywords "`Test`" from `testcol` content field:

```
db.testcol.createIndex({content: "text"})
db.testcol.find({ $text: {$search: "\"Test\""}})
```

How do I translate above two steps that I executed from mongo console to Python code method? eg. something like below. How to build the query?

```
def find_by_keywords(collection, query):
    DATABASE[collection].createIndex({ content: "text"})
    return DATABASE[collection].find({ "how to build the query here?" : "\" + keywords + ""})
```

Comment: PyMongo's  [createIndex](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index) has details for creating _text_ index.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you ve to run this to create text index on the database

```
db.testcol.create_index([('title','text')],language_override="en",default_language='en')
```

Index only 've to be created one time.

Then you can find by keywords on this database, and as u want it:

```
def find_by_keywords(collection, query):
    DATABASE[collection].createIndex({ content: "text"})
    return DATABASE[collection].find({"$text": {"$search": keywords}})
```